# adverb clause without subject

Tags: grammar

Q: Why isn't there any subject for the verb "is"?

> We're not giving society time to think about it and they're not even thinking about it very carefully themselves, _________...

1. obvious it is as
2. as is obvious by (what this ad said)
3. as it's obvious
4. obvious is this as

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a subject. The entire preceding statement is the subject. It's another way of adding a non-defining clause.

- He is a policeman, as is obvious from his uniform.
- He is a policeman, which is obvious from his uniform.